# How to represent Webhook events in a system sequence diagram?

Tags: uml, modeling

I am working on representing interactions of a system that pulls conversations using webhook events in a system sequence diagram.

The actors of User, The system and the External System that sends webhook events that i have registered too already.

Is there a way to represent that or should i don't represent it at all since it's a system - system interaction only and it's not fired by the user?

Comment: @ThomasKilian I am still not sure how or if i am going to represent it

Comment: If you think you audience needs it, then write it down. If you don't think so then let it be. How should we know?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Webhook is usually an HTTP call. HTTP calls are synchronous. Synchronous messages are represented in a sequence diagram by an arrow with a filled triangular arrowhead (as opposed to asynchronous messages, which have an open arrowhead).

If you want to represent a Webhook event in a sequence diagram, you must draw the sending system and the receiving system as lifelines and draw an arrow from the sending system to the receiving system.

You may also choose not to represent this message at all. It depends on the audience. Who is using your sequence diagram? If they may be interested in the Webhook, then draw it. Otherwise, don't draw it.

Comment: Thank you @www.admiraalit.nl, i will represent it since it's a key feature in my work.